# Why Python's turtle fill this?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I don't understand why this figure is filled (I expect nothing is filled here). 
It is not a triangle since I use `penup()`and `pendown()` to move the turtle without drawing an edge).

```
from turtle import *

color('black', 'yellow')
begin_fill()

forward(200)
penup()
left(120)
forward(200)
left(120)
pendown()
forward(200)
end_fill()

exitonclick()
```

Here is what I obtain

[image: bad filling]

It seems `penup()` and `pendown()` are *ignored* here but I did other examples which works as expected while also using `penup` and `pendown`.
Can someone explain me the turtle's filling algortithm please ?

Comment: Evidently having the pen up does not mean that the path your cursor takes will not be used as the boundary to fill. Where did you see different?

Comment: Graphical toolkits (and drawing programs too) often differentiate between drawing the outline of a shape and filling it. One can happen without the other. Turtle might be doing the same. Penup-pendown are not *ignored*, there is no line drawn for that segment.

Answer (score 1):

The filling is independent from the drawing. You can check this in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a05fcd3c7adf6e3a0944da8cf80a3346882e9b3b/Lib/turtle.py#L3331):

```py
self.screen._drawpoly(self._fillitem, self._fillpath, fill=self._fillcolor)
```

As you can see here, `end_fill()` only cares about the `_fillpath`, the path of the turtle since `begin_fill()`. It has nothing to do with drawing.

Just to demonstrate, if you never draw anything (pen is up the whole time), the shape still gets filled:

```py
from turtle import *

color("black", "green")
begin_fill()
penup()
circle(40)
end_fill()

exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. And in addition, it seems that when end_fill() is invoked it closes the figure by adding an edge between the last point and the first (created after begin_fill()). Can someone confirm this ?

Modifying my example as follows:

```
from turtle import *

color('black', 'yellow')
begin_fill()

forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
end_fill()

exitonclick()
```

While the code only draws 2 edges, the result is a colored triangle.

[image]

I expected nothing is filled in this case (this is obviously a little part of a larger project). To avoid the filling it think it is necessary to finish at the same position as I started without adding any new edge. The solution I see is to backmove (in reverse order) along created edges. Here is a solution (`penup()` / `pendown()` can be omitted).

```
from turtle import *

color('black', 'yellow')
begin_fill()

forward(200)
left(120)
forward(200)
penup()
backward(200) # reverse move
left(-120)
backward(200)
pendown()
end_fill()

exitonclick()
```

Here is the result

[image]

It works. Do you see a better way to prevent the filling ?